# Chaincode for Developers error "addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am following the stpes on the page "Chaincode for Developers" (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html#terminal-1-start-the-network).
When running "Terminal1-Start the network" by this line:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-simple.yaml up
```

I got some exception cannot figure out the reason..
[image]
I tried to re-pull all the docker images but it does not work.
All the stuff are running at version 1.0.2.
[image]
[image]

The whole log is over 800K so picking up some onto here:

```
will@ubuntu:~/Documents/blockchain/fabric-samples/chaincode-docker-devmode$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-simple.yaml up
Recreating orderer ... 
Recreating orderer ... done
Recreating peer ... 
Recreating peer ... done
Recreating cli ... 
Recreating cli
Recreating chaincode ... 
Recreating cli ... done
Attaching to orderer, peer, chaincode, cli
orderer      | 2017-10-15 10:11:45.958 UTC [orderer/main] main -> INFO 001 Starting orderer:
orderer      |  Version: 1.0.2
orderer      |  Go version: go1.7.5
orderer      |  OS/Arch: linux/amd64
peer         | 2017-10-15 10:11:46.499 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 001 Starting peer:
peer         |  Version: 1.0.2
peer         |  Go version: go1.7.5
peer         |  OS/Arch: linux/amd64
peer         |  Chaincode:
peer         |   Base Image Version: 0.3.2
peer         |   Base Docker Namespace: hyperledger
peer         |   Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
peer         |   Docker Namespace: hyperledger
peer         | 
peer         | 2017-10-15 10:11:46.499 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 002 Initializing ledger mgmt
peer         | 2017-10-15 10:11:46.499 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 003 Initializing ledger provider
...A LOT OF Log not pasting here.....
orderer      | 2017-10-15 10:11:58.133 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 0c8 Attempting to read seek info message
cli          | Error: Error getting broadcast client: Error connecting to orderer:7050 due to context deadline exceeded
cli          | 2017-10-15 10:12:01.135 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 010 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: operation was canceled"; Reconnecting to {orderer:7050 <nil>}
cli          | Usage:
cli          |   peer channel create [flags]
cli          | 
cli          | Flags:
cli          |   -c, --channelID string   In case of a newChain command, the channel ID to create.
cli          |   -f, --file string        Configuration transaction file generated by a tool such as configtxgen for submitting to orderer
cli          |   -t, --timeout int        Channel creation timeout (default 5)
cli          | 
cli          | Global Flags:
cli          |       --cafile string              Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
cli          |       --logging-level string       Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
cli          |   -o, --orderer string             Ordering service endpoint
cli          |       --test.coverprofile string   Done (default "coverage.cov")
cli          |       --tls                        Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
cli          |   -v, --version                    Display current version of fabric peer server
cli          | 
orderer      | 2017-10-15 10:12:01.137 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 0c9 Error reading from stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
orderer      | 2017-10-15 10:12:01.137 UTC [orderer/main] func1 -> DEBU 0ca Closing Deliver stream
```

I am using the Ubuntu 16.04 (VM on windows) to do the demo.

=========UPDATE ON Oct.30===============

I tried different Ubuntu VM, same issue. Finally it is resolved by using a real Ubuntu. Something really interesting:)

Comment: You get `context deadline exceeded` as a result of transport failure, when the service, in this case the orderer, is not up and running. Could you post docker container logs for further insights. You will get those by doing `docker ps` and then putting the orderer container's id in `docker logs <container-id>`

Comment: hi @jarvis, I did not find the root cause for it, I tried another VM to play this , same issue. Finally I installed a real Ubuntu, it works!